# Chrome installation volume mounts randomly on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, google-chrome

After having installed Google Chrome on Mac OS X 10.6.5, I just noticed that about once or twice a day, the Chrome installation volume mounts for a few seconds and then unmounts.

Which is strange, since I didn't keep the install files around.

What gives?

Comment: Did you install by moving it from the installation volume to Applications or somewhere else on your drive? What if you delete the DMG?

Comment: It's not installing the original DMG, but an update that it downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

That is the Google Chrome auto update running. It's mounts that disc image, updates if necessary and then unmounts it.

It cannot be disabled. There are very [large discussions](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=075667b28fed25e4&hl=en) on this on Google's Chrome site.

I no longer use Chrome. I use the open source Chromium, but it's Snow Leopard only and I built it from source.

As a side note, I'm getting pretty tired of Google getting right up to the evil line of "don't be evil" and hanging out like it's their job.

edited: typos