# strange: random google-XXX.dmg mounts and umounts on OSX

Tags: macos, mount, dmg-image, growl

I just noticed via HardwareGrowl, that a .dmg image file mounted and unmounted all by itself. It was called google-XXX.dmg (where XXX represents a number i did not note down that fast.

I am running Mac OSX 10.6.4 on a MacBook Pro.
No Google product was running at the time of the incident.
Only Google product installed is GoogleAppEngineLauncher.
The .dmg file was gone after the unmount.
I was not fast enough to detect the process, which
initiated the mount.

My Questions:
- Is this the known behaviour of some google update mechanism?
- If so how to stop this?
- I was not able to find an entry in the logs, do you have any suggestion where to look for traces of this event?

There are 2 similar stories from Chrome users i could find (i don't have Chrome installed):
[Chrome installation volume mounts randomly on Mac OS X](https://superuser.com/questions/229968/chrome-installation-volume-mounts-randomly-on-mac-os-x)
http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=3b32d0d9219a1df0&hl=en

Cheers,
Stephan

Comment: I saw this yesterday as well--I assumed at the time that it was Google Chrome autoupdating.

Comment: Though, there -was- a Chrome update just yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it's Google's autoupdate software updating... itself. Try monitoring network connections. I use [Little Snitch](http://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html) for this.